# Hide Material UI grid column on certain breakpoints

Tags: reactjs, grid, material-ui

I'm trying to hide some columns on certain breakpoints, like this:

```
<Grid container>
  <Grid item sm={1} md={0} />
  <Grid item sm={10} md={12}>
    {/* some content goes here */}
  </Grid>
  <Grid item sm={1} md={0} />
</Grid>
```

So in this example first and last columns should not show on medium breakpoint and bigger. I wrote `md={0}`, but that's not a correct code.
Does anyone know the correct way of doing that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the [Material Ui System's display (hiding elements)](https://material-ui.com/system/display/#hiding-elements) feature.

The `display` is not available with `Grid`, so you can use `Box` and use `component` prop and provide `Grid`

[Working demo in codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-ui-grid-breakpoint-issue-fix-ci5he?file=/demo.js:651-1154)

**code snippet**

```js
      <Grid container spacing={3}>
        <Box
          component={Grid}
          className={classes.one}
          item
          xs={1}
          display={{ md: "none" }}
        >
          One
        </Box>
        <Grid className={classes.two} item sm={10} md={12}>
          Two
        </Grid>
        <Box
          component={Grid}
          className={classes.three}
          item
          xs={1}
          display={{ md: "none" }}
        >
          Three
        </Box>
      </Grid>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use Material UI's useMediaQuery

```
import { DataGrid } from "@mui/x-data-grid";
import useMediaQuery from "@mui/material/useMediaQuery";

const data = [
  {
    id: 1,
    column1: "abc",
    column2: "xyz",
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    column1: "abc2",
    column2: "xyz2",
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    column1: "abc3",
    column2: "xyz3",
  },
];
const Hide = () => {
  const matches = useMediaQuery("(max-width:600px)");
  const columns = [
    {
      field: "column1",
      headerName: "Column1",
    },
    {
      field: "column2",
      headerName: "Column2",
      hide: matches,
    },
  ];

  return (
    <div style={{ height: 400, width: "100%" }}>
      <DataGrid rows={data} columns={columns} />
    </div>
  );
};

export default Hide;
```

Comment: This answer is for the wrong component. The question was for the Grid component.